# Trying to get Prerender SPA Plugin to work on Vue.js CLI 3

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, prerender

I'm getting the following error when trying to build:

`Building for production...Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/me/Code/project/index.html'`

Package: `"prerender-spa-plugin": "^3.1.0"`

File: `vue.config.js`:

```
const PrerenderSPAPlugin = require('prerender-spa-plugin');

const Renderer = PrerenderSPAPlugin.PuppeteerRenderer;
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') return;

    return {
      plugins: [
        new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
          staticDir: path.join(__dirname),
          routes: ['/'],
          minify: {
            collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            decodeEntities: true,
            keepClosingSlash: true,
            sortAttributes: true,
          },
          renderer: new Renderer({
            renderAfterDocumentEvent: 'render-event',
          }),
        }),
      ],
    };
  },
};
```

I don't have any routes, only a single index.html page.

Also, when I run `yarn build` and get that error, I try to kill the process in terminal but it keeps returning `Building for production...` without anything happening, and I have to quit terminal for it to stop.

Edit: I've also tried adding `staticDir: path.join(__dirname, './public')` but the build hangs without any errors.

Comment: The same thing happened to me. The problem: I was pre-rendering multiple views but was only dispatching a document event on one of them. The headless browser then hung, waiting for the `document.dispatchEvent` on the other views. If you set `headless: false` in the renderer options and then build your project, you should see Chromium open and then close almost immediately. If it stays open, ensure you have `document.dispatchEvent(new Event('render-event'))` in each view and component you are pre-rendering. Since you only have one view, verify it is actually dispatching an event.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding headless: false to your renderer options. This will open a Chromium browser with your specified array of routes. Open the inspector in the Chromium browser and its very likely that you will see errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Before everything please checkout your main.js file and add this created() to the main.js file

```js
created() {
  document.dispatchEvent(new Event('render-event'));
}
```

Another possible issue with this configuration is that the renderAfterDocumentEvent property is set to 'render-event'. This property specifies the event that the renderer should wait for before rendering the pre-rendered pages. If this event is not being emitted by your application, the renderer may not render the pre-rendered pages correctly.

if it didn't work please change your path :

```js
staticDir: path.resolve('dist'),
```